# Is there a need to include brackets [] when running a query in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have SQL Server 2008 Express Edition installed and is my first time running a SQL query. I noticed that if I select to display the top 1000 rows that the query places brackets [] around the name of the database and its respective columns.

1. Why are there brackets around the name of the database and columns?
2. Is there a need to have these and if so when?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just posted this answer on dba.stack.

They escape names that are not "friendly" - they can be useful if your database names contain special characters (such as spaces, dots or dashes) or represent SQL keywords (such as `USE` or `DATABASE` :-)). Without the square brackets, a query like this will fail:

```
SELECT column FROM database.dbo.table;
```

However if you write the query this way, the keywords are ignored:

```
SELECT [column] FROM [database].dbo.[table];
```

When building scripts or writing solutions that generate scripts from metadata (e.g. generating a script of all tables or all indexes), I always wrap entity names in square brackets so that they will work regardless of what kind of wonky names have been implemented (I am not always doing this for systems I control). You can do this easily using `QUOTENAME` function, e.g.:

```
SELECT QUOTENAME('table'), QUOTENAME('column'), QUOTENAME('database');
```

Results:

```
[table] [column] [database]
```

If you search my answers here for `QUOTENAME` you will find that I use it in a lot of scripts where I'm helping folks automate script generation or building dynamic SQL. Without the square brackets, a lot of people would run into issues running the scripts.

Comment: Thanks. Why did you change the brackets to parenthesis e.g. SELECT QUOTENAME('table'), QUOTENAME('column'), QUOTENAME('database');. Probably could be a different question but when I try it, it results in an error.

Comment: My rule of thumb is: if you *have* to use [square] [brackets], you are probably doing it wrong. (Just don't ask me about all those dynamically-generated pivot statements that have to work with dynamically-generated column names in our system...)

Comment: You're running `SELECT QUOTENAME('table');` and it is returning an error? What error? What version of SQL Server are you using? Functions use parentheses for parameters, not square brackets. `SELECT QUOTENAME['table'];` returns Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 - Invalid column name 'QUOTENAME'.

Comment: @Philip Kelley I agree, however there are so many people out there doing it wrong, I feel compelled to use them, especially for answer here, particularly when generating dynamic SQL or metadata queries that may otherwise depend on logical naming conventions.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - Ah right. I didn't realise that the parentheses were for functions. I replaced table with the name of the table. Sorry for being such a n00b. Just ran the statement again and all I get is the attached screenshot at https://imgur.com/GQmko

Comment: Yes, that query was just an example of what `QUOTENAME` does - notice how it added square brackets around your keywords? It still just returns strings. I was talking about how you might generate a query dynamically, like, say, `SELECT name + ',' FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.yourtablename');` - should be `SELECT QUOTENAME(name) + ',' FROM ...`

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand - Ooh wee- That just went past my head. Something I'll have to pick up on my SQL adventures.

Answer (score 3):

Enclosing a string in square braces is tells SQL Server that it should not try to parse whatever is inside them. This allows you to do use things like SQL reserved words (`select`, `table`, `return`, etc.) as well as spaces in identifiers. They are only required in those cases, but they are not harmful in any case.

Comment: No affect on performance, I think internally they're added anyway by the engine.

Comment: No, certainly nothing you will notice, though there may be a very slight impact at the extreme end (and we're talking real edge case here). Imagine a SQL command you send over the wire that is 64K but becomes 65K when you inject all the square brackets around all the columns (pretend you do this to all tables, columns etc. for safety, rather than just where you need it). You may require extra packets to send this script every time. Completely negligible, surely, but probably non-zero.

Comment: I gave the disclaimer that this was an edge case. But still, imagine all your tables are named a, b, c and your columns are x, y, z. In a large script this can probably approach 1.2x-1.5x the size of the script. Again, edge case, but I'd rather disclose the information and have it be discarded than pretend the information doesn't exist. Especially when I already disclaimed it as such. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't, but it ensures that if you had a db, table or column named as a reserved or keyword, for example `date`, that it wouldn't be confused with that keyword.

Comment: So is it best to include them all the time or just when using reserved keywords?

Comment: I have noticed that a table I am working on includes the brackets as well as single quotes e.g. ['TableName']. Is there a reason for including the single quoates?

Comment: Best to include them to be honest, consistency and you'll never have to worry about collisions.

Comment: Agree with @twilson. You never know when the table name you're using now will become a keyword later. Future-proof your code if it's anything questionable. I always put square brackets around keywords and other potential syntax violations, obviously, but also extend that to non-keywords like Name, Description, etc. Anything that doesn't violate syntax but lights up in a different color in SSMS.